# S3 presentation calculus

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can't understand a -should be- easy calculation. I'm trying to show that S3 has the presentation with two generators and $a^3 = 1 $, $b^2= 1$, $abab=1$.
My coordinator said that $abab=1$ implies $a^b= b^{-1}$, someone could explain the steps ?
And also why $b^{-1} a^s b = (a^s)^b$ ?
Thanks!!!

Comment: what do you mean exactly by $a^b$ ?

Answer (score 0):

[In your context, the power notation $x^g$](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Conjugate_elements) denotes the conjugate $g^{-1}xg$ of $x$ under $g.$ This answers your second question. As for the first one, I think your coordinator meant $a^b=a^{-1},$ not $b^{-1}.$ This is because, knowing that $b^2=1$ i.e. $b=b^{-1}$. $abab=1\iff bab=a^{-1}\iff b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}.$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm trying to go deeper with this power notation, I mean, it's a convention ? It's because I'm working in a quotient group with equivalent classes? Where can I find some materials ? I googled but couldn't find.

Comment: Hi, see the included link. There is no quotient group here. The keyword for googling is "conjugate element". What is important is the notion, not the notation.